# can't work out answer for simple practice quiz, looked in book/online can't find answer

Tags: java

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
System.out.println(x[x[3-2]]);
```

can some one please explain what is going on?
can't find anywhere in my text book or online for an explanation

Comment: Then ditch the book and get a better one.

Comment: I understand that x[3-2] = 2(?) being indice 1 but don't understand what the X before that is doing?

Comment: @Noobprogrammer1234 The same thing. It's x[int] where the `int` also gets its value by a lookup in `x`.

Comment: Try answer the following questions and you'll get it: `What does 3-2 equal to?`   `What does the statement x[1] give you?`   `What does the statement x[2] give you?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3-2 == 1, x[1] == 2; x[2] == 3.

That is, you first evaluate the expression 3-2. Then you evaluate the expression x[1], and so on, up the "levels of nestedness".

Answer (score 2):

- 3 - 2 = 1
- x[3-2] = x[1] = 2
- x[x[3-2]] = x[2] = 3

So output should be "3"

Answer (score 1):

starts out 3-2 = 1

so x[1] = 2 (zero based index)
which means you then have x[2] which is 3

so.. x[x[3-2]] = x[x[1]] = x[2] = 3